# Remove Duplicate Key-Value Pair and Add Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have an ordered dictionary and an array of int both of the same index size:

```
Dict = {"A": "Apple", "A": "Ant", "A": "Apple", "B": "Ball", "B": "Beach", "C": "Cat", "C": "Cat", "D": "Ball"}
Arr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I want to remove duplicates in the dictionary (non-unique key-value pairs) and also sum the ints in the array as such:

```
New Dict = {"A": "Apple", "A": "Ant", "B": "Ball", "B": "Beach", "C": "Cat", "D": "Ball"}
New Arr  = [4, 2, 4, 5, 13, 8]
```

Any suggestions on an elegant way to approach this problem?

Comment: You can't have identical keys in a dictionary in the first place?

Comment: Unfortunately, `OrderedDicts` don't let you duplicate keys, it seems; they just maintain the order of insertion. Can you provide an example of functioning python code that contains the values you want to start with?

Comment: try running your `Dict` initialization and then inspect it and see what happens. By the way this is not an `OrderedDict` and also what do you mean by *sum the ints in the array*? how does `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` is "summed" into `[4, 2, 4, 5, 13, 8]`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this shows a lack of basic understanding of python dictionaries and any map data structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a dict like that (see comments), but you can have a list of tuples:

```
>>> ts = [("A", "Apple"), ("A", "Ant"), ("A", "Apple"), ("B", "Ball"), ("B", "Beach"), ("C", "Cat"), ("C", "Cat"), ("D", "Ball")]
>>> arr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

You can zip the tuples with the array to associate a tuple with its number:

```
>>> sorted(zip(ts, arr))
[(('A', 'Ant'), 2), (('A', 'Apple'), 1), (('A', 'Apple'), 3), (('B', 'Ball'), 4), (('B', 'Beach'), 5), (('C', 'Cat'), 6), (('C', 'Cat'), 7), (('D', 'Ball'), 8)]
```

The function `groupby` from the `itertools` module is very handy on sorted lists. `lambda x: x[0]` means the `(tuple, number)`s are grouped on the `tuple`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [(t, list(g)) for t, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(zip(ts, arr)), lambda x: x[0])]
[(('A', 'Ant'), [(('A', 'Ant'), 2)]), (('A', 'Apple'), [(('A', 'Apple'), 1), (('A', 'Apple'), 3)]), (('B', 'Ball'), [(('B', 'Ball'), 4)]), (('B', 'Beach'), [(('B', 'Beach'), 5)]), (('C', 'Cat'), [(('C', 'Cat'), 6), (('C', 'Cat'), 7)]), (('D', 'Ball'), [(('D', 'Ball'), 8)])]
```

But you don't want the list, you want the `sum` of the numbers `n` of each group `g`:

```
>>> L = [(t, sum(n for _, n in g)) for t, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(zip(ts, arr)), lambda x: x[0])]
>>> L
[(('A', 'Ant'), 2), (('A', 'Apple'), 4), (('B', 'Ball'), 4), (('B', 'Beach'), 5), (('C', 'Cat'), 13), (('D', 'Ball'), 8)]
```

If want your inital format back:

```
>>> list(zip(*L))
[(('A', 'Ant'), ('A', 'Apple'), ('B', 'Ball'), ('B', 'Beach'), ('C', 'Cat'), ('D', 'Ball')), (2, 4, 4, 5, 13, 8)]
>>> ts, ns = list(zip(*L))
>>> ts
(('A', 'Ant'), ('A', 'Apple'), ('B', 'Ball'), ('B', 'Beach'), ('C', 'Cat'), ('D', 'Ball'))
>>> ns
(2, 4, 4, 5, 13, 8)
```